# Prototype plugin need for expanding and hiding divs and remembering state of choices for user

Tags: ajax, prototypejs

While viewing or editing in a rather complicated form, I'd love to be able to have the user close and open "sections" of the page depending on what they are using it for.

The trick is that I'd also like to keep track of those choices as preferences, so that the next time you look at a record of the same sort, you will see the same sections.

What I am envisioning is something like:

```
<div class='expandable'>
  <h2>Some heading</h2>
  <div id='some-stuff-you-might-not-want-to-see' class='expandable-body'>
      ...
  </div>
 </div>
```

When the page is loaded, you'd see the section, but if you clicked on a toggle button on the div, you'd hide it, and if you go to another record of the same type, the section remains hidden.

I don't really want to roll my own, and I'm okay if it is entirely client-side, using cookies to determine which sections to hide. Anybody know of something like this?

Rails 2.3.5, Ruby 1.8.7, using Prototype.

Comment: Edited to remove the rails dependency of this question, and re-tagged.

Answer (score 0):

I think you answered this yourself.  Use a cookie to remember the choice, then use prototype to hide the div(s).  I don't think you'll find a full fledged plug-in to do this for you.

Comment: Yeah, it occured to me that I ought to have asked it as a prototype question rather than a rails question.